# PHP Serverless Slim can't execute imagettftext

Tags: php, aws-lambda, slim, serverless, bref

I intend to use a serverless php function to generate an image with TrueType fonts. In order to do that, I chose **bref** with **Serverless** framework and **composer**.

To process the image and include the text, I'm using `imagettftext` function from `gd` library. I ran `php -S localhost:8000 index.php` for local testing purposes. It worked fine, I got the output image as I expected it.

Thus I ran  `composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev` and then `serverless deploy` to create a AWS Lamda function. However, when I called the deployed function's endpoint, it showed a **Slim Application Error** - without any detail:

> A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience.

So I took a look at AWS Cloudwatch logs and found this error message:

> Message: Call to undefined function imagettftext()

Searching about this error, I found out it's often related to `gd` library missing. Then I compared `phpinfo()` from local test to the one from deployed function. Both have `gd` installed, the difference is that the local one has `FreeType Support` enabled.

Could you help me to find a way to enable this `FreeType Support` also for the serverless function? Is it possible to require this support through `composer.json`?

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue open on GitHub at the moment regarding compiling PHP with `freetype` support, which explains the result you're seeing: https://github.com/brefphp/bref/issues/497.

`GD` needs to know about `freetype` as it's compiled into `PHP`, so I doubt you would be able to include it with `composer`